# String partial match

Tags: android

i want partial matching of string in java e.g

String s1 = "method";

String s2 = "this is wonderful method i am using ";

if s1 complete exists in s2 then s2 returns.   any one has algorithm or other flexible code, Thank you in advance.

Comment: you need the indexOf method in String class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
if (s2.contains(s1))
    return s2;
```

Comment: it is case sensitive how case sensitivity will remove

Comment: Yes, this is case-sensitive. You can just create a copy of the strings and use toLowerCase() to get rid of the case sensitivity.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java.String.indexOf(), as described [here](http://www.javadb.com/check-if-string-contains-another-string).

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty straight forward.

```
if(s2.contains(s1)){
    //do your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest would be to use String.contains as in `if( s2.contains(s1) ) return s2;`
Or you could use regex to match

`if( s2.matches("(?i).*" + s1 + ".*") )
{
return s2;
}`

Might be a bit overkill though, but good to know a few different ways to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `contains()` method of `String` class, Please study the following example,

```
public class TestClass 
{
    private String getString ( String str1, String str2 ) 
    {
        if ( str2.contains (str1) )
        {
            return str2;
        }
        else
        {
            return "-1";
        }
    }

    public static void main ( String args[] )
    {
        String s1 = "method";
        String s2 = "this is wonderful method i am using";

        TestClass tc = new TestClass();

        System.out.println ( tc.getString(s1, s2) );

    }
}

// Output 
// this is wonderful method i am using
```